# C# wrap text programmatically from excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have a c# console program that downloads an `.xls` file that gets converted to `.csv` file using

```
string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + sourceFile + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\"";

OleDbConnection conn = null;
StreamWriter wrtr = null;
OleDbCommand cmd = null;
OleDbDataAdapter da = null;
try
{
    conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
    conn.Open();


    cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + worksheetName + "$]", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    wrtr = new StreamWriter(targetFile);

    da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
```

In one of the columns, the text needs to be word wrapped. How can I do that? Data looks like this

`"The District of Columbia

ZIP 11101.

"`
The column should actually be `"The District of Columbia ZIP 11101."`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing line breaks using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365719/removing-line-breaks-using-c-sharp)

Comment: no, my problem is different. I cannot check for each field because my xls file is very large.

Comment: Are you trying to wrap or unwrap the text coming from the OleDbCommand? The title suggests that you want to wrap text, but the last part of the question seems to indicate that you want wrapped text to become un-wrapped.

Answer (score 1):

After you supply text you should set the cell's IsTextWrapped style to true

```
worksheet.Cells[0, 0].Style.IsTextWrapped = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line breaks using something like this:

```
string noWraps = source.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

Comment: How can I do it for a whole column??

Comment: Well, you need to iterate over the rows in the `DataTable` you fill in your code. Call someting like `dt.Rows[i][j] = dt.Rows[i][j].Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");`.

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten, I used Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "") and it worked.

Comment: Great! The equivalent to "Thanks, it works" on StackOverflow is to accept the answer and maybe even upvote it :-)