# WrapText for column in Excel programmatically

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I'm trying to set WrapText property to true with C#.

```
Range rng = sheet.get_Range("A:A", System.Type.Missing);
rng.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 50;
rng.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
rng.EntireRow.AutoFit();
rng.WrapText = true;
```

but it doesn't work without any exceptions. What's wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this would work, but maybe set the `WrapText` value before calling `AutoFit()` ?

Comment: Hi just take a look at this post hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076961/c-sharp-wrap-text-programmatically-from-excel

Comment: @RamRS is right, if you want a constant width in a column, then set the size and wrapText = true, but delete the autoFits

Answer (score 11):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

//Initial Declarations//
Excel.Workbook destinationXlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet destinationXlWorkSheet;
Excel.Application destinationXlApp;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

//Launch Excel App//
destinationXlApp = new Excel.Application();

//Load WorkBook in the opened Excel App//
destinationXlWorkBook = destinationXlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

//Load worksheet-1 in the workbook//
destinationXlWorkSheet =
 (Excel.Worksheet)destinationXlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

//Set Text-Wrap for all rows true//
destinationXlWorkSheet.Rows.WrapText = true;

//Or, set it for specific rows//
destinationXlWorkSheet.Rows[3].WrapText = true;
destinationXlWorkSheet.Rows[5].WrapText = true;

//Edit individual cells//
 xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "ID";                  
 xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Name";
 xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "1";
 xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2] = "One";
 xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "2";
 xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 2] = "Two";


//Save and close the Excel//
destinationXlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\UtkarshSinha\\Documents\\SAP\\text.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

//Start quitting and closing Excel//
destinationXlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
destinationXlApp.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(destinationXlWorkSheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(destinationXlWorkBook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(destinationXlApp);
```

Answer (score 3):

I am duping **A LOT** of code here, for my entire solution, `WrapText` being one of it. I figure it might come in handy to someone someday.

MAIN PROGRAM:

```
    public int counter;
    public void ExportPartsToExcelButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Type officeType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
        if (officeType != null)
        {
            if (CurrentID != 0)
            {
                counter = 1;
                GeneratePartsXLSX();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBoxEx.Show(this, "No address selected!", "Warning!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBoxEx.Show(this, "Install Microsoft Excel!", "Warning!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        }
        
    }
    public void GeneratePartsXLSX()
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
        string filename = GlobalStrings.building_house_address;
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\";

        filename = filename.Replace("/", "+");

        if (!File.Exists(path + filename + ".xlsx"))
        {
            DataGridParts.ExportPartsToExcel(path + filename + ".xlsx"); //You have to include the ".xlsx" extension, otherwise the Office interop detects a possible dot (.) in the file name as an extension. Example: road.block instead of road.block.xlsx
            MessageBoxEx.Show(this, "Saved to Desktop");
        }
        else
        {
            if (!File.Exists(path + "\\" + filename + " (" + (counter) + ")" + ".xlsx"))
            {
                DataGridParts.ExportPartsToExcel(path + filename + " (" + (counter) + ")" + ".xlsx");
                MessageBoxEx.Show(this, "Saved to Desktop");
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;
                GeneratePartsXLSX();
            }
        }
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
    }
```

CLASS:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SAVETOEXCELPROGRAM
{
public static class ExportToExcel
{
    public static void ExportPartsToExcel(this System.Data.DataTable DataTable, string ExcelFilePath = null)
    {
        int ColumnsCount;
        int RowShift = 7;

        ColumnsCount = DataTable.Columns.Count;

        // load excel, and create a new workbook
        Application Excel = new Application();
        Excel.Workbooks.Add();

        // single worksheet
        _Worksheet Worksheet = Excel.ActiveSheet;
        Excel.Sheets[1].Name = "WHATEVER";

        Worksheet.Columns.NumberFormat = "@"; //Force the "Text" format, so that 1/2 won't get converted to 1st of February for example
        Worksheet.Columns.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft; //Text aligment 
        Worksheet.Columns.VerticalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter; //Text aligment

        object[,] Title = new object[5, 1]; //Array range starts at [1,1], the content index starts at [0,0]

        if (GlobalStrings.building_alterantive_addresses.Length == 0)
        {
            if (GlobalStrings.building_postcode.Length != 0)
            {
                Title[0, 0] = "DATE: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm");
                Title[2, 0] = "ADDRESS: " + GlobalStrings.building_house_street + " " + GlobalStrings.building_house_number + GlobalStrings.building_house_id + ", " + GlobalStrings.building_postcode + " " + GlobalStrings.building_area;
                Title[3, 0] = "C.C.: " + GlobalStrings.building_cadastral_community + ", BUILDING NO.: " + GlobalStrings.building_building_number + ", PLOT NO.: " + GlobalStrings.building_plot_number;
            }
            else
            {
                Title[0, 0] = "DATE: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm");
                Title[2, 0] = "ADDRESS: " + GlobalStrings.building_house_street + " " + GlobalStrings.building_house_number + GlobalStrings.building_house_id;
                Title[3, 0] = "C.C.: " + GlobalStrings.building_cadastral_community + ", BUILDING NO.: " + GlobalStrings.building_building_number + ", " + GlobalStrings.building_plot_number;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (GlobalStrings.building_postcode.Length != 0)
            {
                Title[0, 0] = "DATE: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm");
                Title[2, 0] = "ADDRESS: " + GlobalStrings.building_house_street + " " + GlobalStrings.building_house_number + GlobalStrings.building_house_id + ", " + GlobalStrings.building_postcode + " " + GlobalStrings.building_area;
                Title[3, 0] = "C.C.: " + GlobalStrings.building_cadastral_community + ", BUILDING NO.: " + GlobalStrings.building_building_number + ", PLOT NO.: " + GlobalStrings.building_plot_number;
                Title[4, 0] = "LOOK ALSO: " + GlobalStrings.building_alterantive_addresses;
            }
            else
            {
                Title[0, 0] = "DATE: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm");
                Title[2, 0] = "ADDRESS: " + GlobalStrings.building_house_street + " " + GlobalStrings.building_house_number + GlobalStrings.building_house_id;
                Title[3, 0] = "C.C.: " + GlobalStrings.building_cadastral_community + ", BUILDING NO.: " + GlobalStrings.building_building_number + ", PLOT NO.: " + GlobalStrings.building_plot_number;
                Title[4, 0] = "LOOK ALSO: " + GlobalStrings.building_alterantive_addresses;
            }
        }

        Range TitleRange = Worksheet.get_Range((Range)(Worksheet.Cells[5, 1]), (Range)(Worksheet.Cells[1, 1]));
        TitleRange.Value = Title;
        TitleRange.Font.Bold = true;
        TitleRange.Font.Size = 10;

        object[] Header = new object[14]; //Number of Headers

        Header[0] = "PART";
        Header[1] = "SHARE";
        Header[2] = "CRP";
        Header[3] = "+/-";
        Header[4] = "OWNER";
        Header[5] = "ADDRESS";
        Header[6] = "POSTCODE";
        Header[7] = "AREA";
        Header[8] = "COUNTRY";
        Header[9] = "SOCIAL";
        Header[10] = "TYPE";
        Header[11] = "DESCRIPTION";
        Header[12] = "COMMENT";
        Header[13] = "CODE";

        int MaxCol = Header.Length;

        Range HeaderRange = Worksheet.get_Range((Range)(Worksheet.Cells[RowShift, 2]), (Range)(Worksheet.Cells[RowShift, MaxCol + 1])); //MaxCol+1, because we have to shift the Array position by 1, as the first column is set to "ColumnWidth = 0.1"
        HeaderRange.Value = Header;
        HeaderRange.Font.Bold = true;
        HeaderRange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);
        HeaderRange.Borders.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;

        // DataCells
        int RowsCount = DataTable.Rows.Count;

        object[,] Cells = new object[RowsCount, ColumnsCount]; //Array range starts at [1,1], the content index starts at [0,0]

        for (int j = 0; j < RowsCount; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 3; i <= ColumnsCount - 2; i++) //With this you control the data range, starts with 0, you can exclude data with an " if (i != 0 && i != 1 && ... && i= 5)
            {
                Cells[j, i - 3] = DataTable.Rows[j][i]; //with i you control the horizontal placement of the data in the worksheet
            }
        }

        Range CellRange = Worksheet.get_Range((Range)(Worksheet.Cells[RowShift + 1, 2]), (Range)(Worksheet.Cells[RowShift + RowsCount, MaxCol + 1])); //MaxCol+1, because we have to shift the Array position by 1, as the first column is set to "ColumnWidth = 0.1"
        CellRange.Value = Cells;
        CellRange.Borders.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;

        Worksheet.Columns[1].ColumnWidth = 0.1; //If this was set on AutoFit the Column 1 would get extended to the Title Width, because they share the column.
        Worksheet.Columns[2].ColumnWidth = 3;
        Worksheet.Columns[3].ColumnWidth = 4;
        Worksheet.Columns[4].ColumnWidth = 3;
        Worksheet.Columns[5].ColumnWidth = 2;
        Worksheet.Columns[6].ColumnWidth = 13;
        Worksheet.Columns[7].ColumnWidth = 15;
        Worksheet.Columns[8].ColumnWidth = 4;
        Worksheet.Columns[9].ColumnWidth = 8;
        Worksheet.Columns[10].ColumnWidth = 6;
        Worksheet.Columns[11].ColumnWidth = 10;
        Worksheet.Columns[12].ColumnWidth = 18;
        Worksheet.Columns[13].ColumnWidth = 16;
        Worksheet.Columns[14].ColumnWidth = 18;

        Worksheet.Columns[MaxCol + 1].ColumnWidth = 15; //Set the Width of the last Column

        for (int b = 2; b <= MaxCol; b++) //If we wanted to include the "Header[14]", we would have to set MaxCol+1, because the Array (not the DataTable) is shifted by +1. These are Excel Worksheet settings!
        {
            Worksheet.Columns[b].WrapText = true;
            //Worksheet.Columns[b].AutoFit();
        }

        for (int b = 2; b <= MaxCol + 1; b++)
        {
            Worksheet.Columns[b].Font.Size = 7;
        }





        Worksheet.PageSetup.Orientation = XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
        Worksheet.PageSetup.TopMargin = 0.5;
        Worksheet.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 0.5;
        Worksheet.PageSetup.RightMargin = 0.5;
        Worksheet.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 0.5;

        // check fielpath
        if (ExcelFilePath != null && ExcelFilePath != "")
        {
            Worksheet.SaveAs(ExcelFilePath);
            Excel.Quit();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(Worksheet);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(TitleRange);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(HeaderRange);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(CellRange);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(Excel);
        }
        else
        // no filepath is given
        {
            Excel.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The most relevant part of this answer worked for me:  
for (int b = 2; b <= MaxCol; b++)
       Worksheet.Columns[b].WrapText = true;

Answer (score 0):

```
workSheet.Cells["A1:T1"].Style.WrapText = true;
```

Comment: Please add some comments describing how your code fixes the problem in order to improve this answer.